# Compiling Dynamically Linked Library in C++ with Run Path Issue

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-construction, g++

I'm busy trying to compile and link a c++ program using the following make file

```
driver.so:driver.cpp
        g++ -c driver.cpp -o driver.so 
        g++ -L/tokenlib/libtokenlib.so driver.so -o linked
```

but I'm getting the error

```
g++ -c driver.cpp -o driver.so 
g++ -L/tokenlib/libtokenlib.so driver.so -o linked
driver.so: In function `main':
driver.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `tokenlib::acquire_token()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [driver.so] Error 1
```

and my file hierarchy is

```
/root
    makefile
    driver.cpp
    /tokenlib
        libtokenlib.so
```

I've been told that adding -Wl,-rpath=./tokenlib to my g++ arguements would solve the problem so I tried like this

```
    driver.so:driver.cpp
        g++ -c driver.cpp -o driver.so -Wl,-rpath=./tokenlib 
        g++ -L/tokenlib/libtokenlib.so driver.so -o linked -Wl,-rpath=./tokenlib
```

but it still isn't working.

I'm a complete novice and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `-L/tokenlib/libtokenlib.so` Should point to a path, not to a file?

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to to give me the same error. I changed it to  g++ -L/tokenlib driver.so -o linked or if I try g++ -L/tokenlib tokenlib.so driver.so -o linked I get g++: error: tokenlib.so: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The linker usually refers to `.a` (stub) libraries, not to `.so` files!
`-L` options specify the paths, the lnker should take in account.
The `-l<mystuff>` option tries to resolve a library named `libmystuff.a` from any of the given path's of the `-L` options, or compiler intrinsic library search paths.